# How to Trim consecutive Characters VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking to trim (drop) consecutive characters, and everything in front of it in vb.net.

An example of the output:

```
*017834
^018730
%018411
```

What I'd like to do - is trim '01' and any character in front of it. So my desired output would be:

```
7834
8730
8411
```

I attempted to use

```
Dim charsToTrim() As Char = { "01"c}
```

However, you're only allowed to use 1 character at a time this way in vb.net.  Since i may have "0" or "1", I can't break it up like this:

```
Dim charsToTrim() As Char = { "0"c,"1",c}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Function Trim01(ByVal input As String) As String
    Dim pos = input.IndexOf("01")

    Return If(pos >= 0, input.Substring(pos + "01".Length), input)
End Function
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.